# Newbie question about return keyword in Python functions

Tags: python, function, return

I am currently working in codecademy on a Python course and while trying to define a function that takes in a list and returns a list with the length of that same list added to the list I realized I keeping getting "None" instead of a full list and was wondering why.

I was able figure out the correct solution but for my own education, I'm curious why my original code didn't work as intended.

```
#This is the first one I tried 
def append_size(lst):
  return lst.append(len(lst))
  

#Uncomment the line below when your function is done
print(append_size([23, 42, 108]))
# returns None instead of [23, 42, 108]
```

```
#This is the correct function
def append_size(lst): 
  lst.append(len(lst))
  return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

`lst.append` always returns `None`. It modifies `lst` in place, so all you need to do is return `lst` itself.

```
def append_size(lst):
    lst.append(len(lst))
    return lst
```

---

This is a violation, though, of the usually conventional (followed by `list.append` itself) that a function or method should either modify an argument in-place and return `None` or return a new value based on the unchanged argument.

There's no particular need to return `lst`, since presumably the caller already has a reference to the list, as they were able to pass it as an argument in the first place.